# Extracting Data Between two Characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following format in Excel and I am trying to extract the data between the characters:

```
First Last <flastname@xxxx.com>
```

I need to extract the email address between < and > into its own cell

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to do this with a formula or with a macro?

Answer (score 9):

use the following formula, assuming your data is in cell A2

```
=mid(left(A2,find(">",A2)-1),find("<",A2)+1,len(A2))
```

To avoid error message if your data is not conforming, you can use the following in excel 2007 and up:

```
=iferror(mid(left(A2,find(">",A2)-1),find("<",A2)+1,len(A2)),"")
```

Comment: +1.  You might want to note that `IFERROR` is in Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: @DougGlancy Edit done.

Answer (score 3):

For maybe a simpler approach, or maybe just a different approach without formulas.

You can do a `Replace` on the data range, twice.

First Replace `*<` with `(blank)`

Then Replace `>` with `(blank)`.

Done (unless some of your data doesn't conform!!!)

Comment: Yea, just do this.

Comment: if you do this, use `>*` if you can have data after `>`

Answer (score 2):

The answer of nutsch doesn't work if the two characters are the same.

I think this is better:

=MID(K370, FIND("a",K370)+1, FIND("b", K370, FIND("a", K370)+1)-FIND("a",K370)-1)

where K370 is your source cell and "a" and "b" are the two consecutive chars.

Answer (score -1):

you can select the column of your data and choose "text to columns" in "Data" tab in the ribbon. then choose "delimited" and click next. then in delimiters type "<" and click next. then click finish. do the same way for delimiter ">" and it's ok. note this is not the simple way bat it will learn you a soloution for other questions.
have fun