# want to extract email address from a string of characters -- pretty close

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am close to the end, I just need to add something in to remove the open and close parenthesis and then add a semicolon. I got this far by googling; I just need one more piece to the puzzle. :)

Bonus point if you want to explain the formula to me : ) I get it theoretically and had hoped to figure out the rest, but I am wasting too much time and need to just do the work.

Thanks so much --

Here is what I have so far:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A17,FIND(" ",A17&" ",FIND("@",A17))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A17))),LEN(A17)
```

Original string: `first last (first.last@company.com)`
Result: `(first.last@company.com)`

Comment: You just want to remove everything up to and including the first parenthesis, remove the last parenthesis and then tack on a semi-colon on the end?  So, in the end you just want to end up with an email plus semi colon?  Are the input strings _always_ in the format you show in the "Original string" example (like nothing after the closing parenthesis)?

Comment: For this project, yes, the input strings are always the same. And yes, I am looking to end up with email address and a semi-colon. Actually, I guess I need a space too. I was going to combine all add to an email message at the end of the day. If you have other ideas, I am open. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in the question I marked as a possible dupe ([Extracting Data Between two Characters in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/491907/extracting-data-between-two-characters-in-excel)), you can use what's in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/491908/23133), modify the delimiter characters, plus use the Concatenate to add the semi-colon to make it specific to your need:

`=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(MID(LEFT(A17,FIND(")",A17)-1),FIND("(",A17)+1,LEN(A17)),";"),"")`

Changes

`first last (first.last@company.com)` to `first.last@company.com;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("(",A1),""),")",";")

If you do not want to use a formula, these parts can be removed with simple
```

Find/Replace too. First, replace "*(" with nothing, then Replace  ")" with ";" 
(without the quotation marks).