# Extract text between emails with < >

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Original link: [Extracting Data Between two Characters in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/491907/extracting-data-between-two-characters-in-excel/949489#949489)

I have a combination of cells where some have nicknames and some are without nicknames.

Some will have nickname `< >` emails and some will just be an email address. If I copy and paste the following into the whole row, some cells will be empty:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A1, FIND(">", A1)-1), FIND("<", A1)+1, LEN(A1)), "")
```

If a particular cell does not contain `<` and `>`, I would like the formula to just take an exact copy and paste it with the same row as the others so I can just copy and paste the whole row without checking whether some cells are empty.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please show some sample data and your desired result

Comment: @Aaron Are you just trying to strip out the < > symbols?

Comment: http://s756.photobucket.com/user/AaronJoYee/media/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-03%20at%2010.11.45%20AM_zpspxy0qh4c.png.html

Comment: COLUMN A4, B4 & D4 works fine but C4 is empty as cell C1 do not have any nickname/first or last name and no < > that is why C4 is empty.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace the last `""` with `A1` so that if excel doesn’t find a `<` or `>` it will return the entire contents of `A1` instead of blank:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A1, FIND(">", A1)-1), FIND("<", A1)+1, LEN(A1)),A1)
```

Comment: Aaron, is this a satisfied answer? If yes, please mark as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to describe what’s not working.