# Extract part of cell in Excel between to identical characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found this [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/491907/extracting-data-between-two-characters-in-excel) but the first solution doesn't work if the two characters are identical. Looking for something as short as reasonably possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1)-FIND(":",A1,1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[2]")
```

[image]

---

Or:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",999)),1000,999))
```

[image]